# Remove elements in list with a list of Int (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell

I am writing function that take a list of `Int`, a list of general type `a` and remove all elements that have index in the list of Int.

For example: `removeEl [1,3,4] [1,2,3,4,5,6]` return `[1,3,6]`
or `removeEl [1,2] "Firefox"` return `"Fefox"`

Here is my attempt:

```
removeEl :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
removeEl [] xs = []
removeEl ns [] = []
removeEl (n:ns) (x:xs) | n == 0 = removeEl ns xs
                       | n > 0 = x:removeEl (n-1) xs
```

I realize `(n-1)` is an `Int`, not `[Int]` so it fail. Do I need to write an auxiliary function to use?

Comment: In the `n > 0` case, you would also need to decrease the following indices (not just the first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a new list, but every item in that list needs to be decremented, because you've shifted the positions of every element of the second argument. This is true whether or not you've actually removed the head element.

```
removeEl (n:ns) (x:xs) | n == 0 = removeEl (map pred ns) xs
                       | n > 0 = x:removeEl (map pred (n:ns)) xs
```

There's a lot of opportunity to refactor this, but nothing I've played with feels significantly simpler.

Also, your first base case is wrong: with no items in the index list, you want to return *everything*, not *nothing*:

```
remove [] xs = xs
```

(Keep in mind this only works if the first argument is monotonically increasing.)

---

You can also avoid the explicit recursion with a list comprehension:

```
removeEl ns xs = [x | (n,x) <- zip [0..] xs, not(n `elem` ns)]
```

Comment: I tried you code but it says `No instance for (Num (Int -> Int)) in the first argument of map`, the error is at line of case `n==0`

Comment: Because I still forget that negative literals are a pain in Haskell.

Comment: One could also simplify it a bit by using `pred` instead of `subtract 1`

Comment: Ah, I forgot about `pred`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your algorithm is `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the list and `m` is the number of indices to remove. It also has the unfortunate requirement that the list of indices must be ordered. Here's a `~O(n*log(m))` solution that doesn't require the indices be ordered.

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

removeE1 indices xs = go 0 xs
  where is = Set.fromList indices
        go _ [] = []
        go n (y:ys) | n `Set.member` is = go (n+1) ys
                    | otherwise         = y : go (n+1) ys
```

And this could be improved a bit by using a hash map.